# Nifi - MergeContent - Multiple CSV files - counter

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to merge 6 CSV files into 1

I use

ListHDFS >> FechHDFS >> UpdateAttribute >> MergeContent >> QueryRecord >> ...

ListHDFS >> FechHDFS >> UpdateAttribute is repeated as the number of files to merge ( 6 times)

because I shoud to give for each file the fragment.index parameter and an allias ( used later for the join query in QueryRecord )

[image]

The UpdateAttribute for one of the files:

[image]

Is there a way to avoid multiple processors to get the files ListHDFS >> FechHDFS >>  UpdateAttribute

How to reduce is into one ListHDFS >> FechHDFS >> UpdateAttribute and give a different fragment.index for each different file which shloud be between 0 and 6 (max number of files) ?

I tried NextInt() to attribute a new fragment.index value but it is incremental, not suitable for multiple executions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the solution in this thread:

[Link to the solution](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Count-number-of-incoming-flowfiles/m-p/336224#M232202)